# UIProgressView: How to get the old style?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiprogressview

I'm searching for the old style of the UIProgressView:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090620-dagnbt6eh2s884nfkbkqgne1re.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090620-dagnbt6eh2s884nfkbkqgne1re.jpg)

The only UIProgressViewStyle, I'm able to present is this:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090620-ewujnw3r62qnb91qpbdh8iktne.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090620-ewujnw3r62qnb91qpbdh8iktne.jpg)

Is the old one still available? Setting the property `UIProgressViewStyle` always leads to the blue UIProgressView.

Comment: i was never aware that this old style was available.. what sdk version are you using ... and what were you using when you last saw the old version??

Comment: I've never used the old style. I saw it in Erica Sadun's iPhone book. The provided an example, which was set to SDK 2.0.

Comment: i know erica sadun's book has a section on un-published api's - are you sure it wasn't in this section??

Comment: Yepp, it's in chapter four. The code uses standard Apple documented code. I think Apple simply have replaced the graphics after 2.0 :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it'a worth, another way of accessing the old-style progress bar is to create a UIProgressView control in the usual way.  As of iOS 4.1, you can get the old appearance by setting the progress view's style to the undocumented value of 100.

This avoids using an undocumented class, or even calling undocumented methods.  However, I'm sure Apple still won't approve..  ;-)

Dave

Comment: Oh - and if you do use this undocumented style to change the style of a UIProgressView loaded from a nib, then you should call 'sizeToFit' after setting the style.  This is 'cos the old style is twice the height of the newer blue progress bar.

Comment: For information, that style doesnt work anymore properly on iOS5.

Comment: i think there is very little use for answers that provides code that won't be accepted by app store..

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two styles for the UIProgressView. The default which is referenced as UIProgressViewStyleDefault, and the one you are referring to is called UIProgressViewStyleBar.

those are set as the following
yourUIProgressView.ProgressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyleBar;

or

set nothing for the default.

Answer (score 2):

She wrote her book when the SDK was still NDA and before it used IB. Many, many changes occurred after that time.

Answer (score 2):

It's **UIProgressBar**, a private subclass of UIProgressView.

You can use it in this way, but Apple might reject your app:

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"UIProgressBar") alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 90.0f)];
```